# Store GeoJSON polygons in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geo, geojson

I have the following problem with MongoDB. I got some geo data from my home country and i have to store them into mongodb to set up a simple Web Feature Service. This service will mostly do bounding box queries using the `$within` operator. The data is in GeoJSON format. Therefore i imported at first the Villages and Cities which are represented as points (`[1,2]`) in this format. No problem. Next step rivers and streets which are LineStrings and according to GeoJSON represented this way `[[1,2],[3,4]]`. But when importing the districts (which are in fact polygon and according to the GeoJSON specification 3 dim arrrays) i got the error  `geo values have to be numbers` when creating the index.

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({"geometry.coordinates" : "2d"});
```

All data are valid GeoJSON, and are in plain 2d coordinates in EPSG:4326 projection.

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that mongo 2.3.2 development release now has GeoJSON support:
[Release Notes for MongoDB 2.4](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4/#new-geospatial-indexes-with-geojson-and-improved-spherical-geometry)

Answer (score 13):

With MongoDB 2.4 use the "2dsphere" index for GeoJSON Points, LineStrings and Polygons.

For example, you can create this index:

```
db.mycoll.ensureIndex( { loc : "2dsphere" } )
```

And store this LineString:

```
{ loc : { type : "LineString" , coordinates : [ [ 1 , 2 ] , [ 3 , 4 ] ] } }
```

See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/2dsphere/.

Comment: 2.6 will support MultiPoint, MultiLineString, MultiPolygon and GeometryCollection
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this same thing myself to set up a GeoFence feature. What I did was store "polygon" data as a series of coordinate, and a center. For instance:

```js
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId( "4f189d132ae5e92272000000" ),
    "name" : "Alaska",
    "points" : [ 
        { "coords" : [ 
            -141.0205, 
            70.0187 ] 
        }, 

        ...

        { "coords" : [ 
            -141.0205, 
            70.0187 ] 
        } 
    ],
    "center" : { 
        "coords" : [ 
          -153.6370465116279, 
          61.42329302325581 ] 
    } 
}
```

In my application (in python) I am using the [shapely library](http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html#polygons). What I first do is find a list of objects that have a center closest to my point. Then on the client side (python) I use shapely convert each large coordinate array to a polygon, and then test the regions to find which ones contain my point.

So you *can* store polygon data in MongoDB as just data, and use some other precomputed 2d index like a center.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try from the mongo shell:

```
// Polygon in GeoJson format
var poly = {};
poly.name = 'GeoJson polygon';
poly.geo = {};
poly.geo.type = 'Polygon';
poly.geo.coordinates = [
    [ [ -80.0, 30.0 ], [ -40.0, 30.0 ], [ -40.0, 60.0 ], [-80.0, 60.0 ], [ -80.0, 30.0 ] ]
];
db.foo.insert(poly);
db.foo.ensureIndex({geo: "2dsphere" });
```

Comment: I just started working with Polygons in MongoDB but I find the shape of the polygon structure weird... If a shape is a set of points, why the array of those points is inside another array? Shouldn't `poly.geo.coordinates = [[-80.0, 30.0], [-40.0, 30.0], ... ]` be enough?

Comment: @Loupax Coordinates of a Polygon are an array of LinearRing coordinate arrays. The first element in the array represents the exterior ring. Any subsequent elements represent interior rings (or holes).(http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id4)

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB's geospatial features currently only support storing points, not shapes or lines. You are however able to query for points using circles, rectangles, or polygons.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#polygon), a polygon could be stored as a GeoJSON polygon like:

```
{
  type: "Polygon",
  coordinates: [ [ [ 0 , 0 ] , [ 3 , 6 ] , [ 6 , 1 ] , [ 0 , 0  ] ] ]
}
```

It's a simple one with a simple ring but it's also possible to store a polygon with multiple rings.