# MongoDb C# - How to store GeoJSON in a document

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

It is hard to find out GeoJSON in MongoDb C# Driver.

I try to create a document like this:

```
new BsonDocument()
{
    { "PointType", "Building"},
    { "Name", "My Place"},
    { "Location", ??? }
}
```

and try to fill in something like `GeoJson.Point(new GeoJson2DCoordinates(0.0000, 0.0000)).ToBsonDocument()` in the `???` above.

but once I create index for the `Location` and try to insert this document, MongoDb wan't happy. It throws `location object expected, location array not in correct format`.

Is there any sample or documentation for C# with `BsonDocument` and GeoJSON?

Any other suggestion to insert GeoJSON value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should use `IndexKeys.Geo2DSphere` instead of `IndexKeys.Geo2D` to store GeoJSON point.

```
var keys = Builders<BsonDocument>.IndexKeys.Geo2DSphere("Location");
await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(keys);
```

Then I can do:

```
new BsonDocument()
{
    { "PointType", "Building"},
    { "Name", "My Place"},
    { "Location", GeoJson.Point(new GeoJson2DCoordinates(lng, lat)).ToBsonDocument() }
}
```

Comment: Same case here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137127/store-geojson-polygons-in-mongodb